# Modify array to stop object from being nested

Tags: javascript

I have an example array

```
const array = [
      { obj: [{ fields: { title: 'titleValue1' } }, { fields: { title: 'titleValue2' } }] },
      { obj: [{ fields: { title: 'titleValue3' } }, { fields: { title: 'titleValue4' } }] },
    ]
```

I'm looking to modify the array to:

```
  const modifiedArray = [
      { obj: [{ title: 'titleValue1' }, { title: 'titleValue2' }] },
      { obj: [{ title: 'titleValue3' }, { title: 'titleValue4' }] },
    ]
```

So when I loop over the modified array I can call 'obj.title' instead of 'obj.fields.title'
I think this can be achieved using .map. So far I have tried:

```
    const ammendedArray = array.map(item => ({ ...item, title: item.map(e => e.fields) }))
```

But returning 'item.map is not a function'
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: item is the object `obj : [{...}]`, You should use `item.obj.map...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are trying to use map for an item in the top level array. Which is like this for the first item,

```
{ obj: [{ fields: { title: 'titleValue1' } }, { fields: { title: 'titleValue2' } }] }
```

As you can see `item` is an object. You can not map through an object. What you can do is map through `item.obj`

```
const ammendedArray = array.map(item => ({ ...item, title: item.obj.map(e => e.fields) }))
```

But it will not solve your problem you will get a wrong array of objects like this,

```
[
  { 
    obj: [{ fields: { title: 'titleValue1' } }, { fields: { title: 'titleValue2' } }], 
    title: [{ title: 'titleValue1' }, { title: 'titleValue2' }] 
  },
  ...
]
```

You will have to update the `obj` key instead. What you need to do is the following,

```
const array = [
      { obj: [{ fields: { title: 'titleValue1' } }, { fields: { title: 'titleValue2' } }] },
      { obj: [{ fields: { title: 'titleValue3' } }, { fields: { title: 'titleValue4' } }] },
    ]

const res = array.map((item) => {
  return {
    obj: item.obj.map(i => {
       return i.fields
    })
  };
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will explain.

Answer (score 0):

I could reach to that like this :)

```
const array = [
      { obj: [{ fields: { title: 'titleValue1' } }, { fields: { title: 'titleValue2' } }] },
      { obj: [{ fields: { title: 'titleValue3' } }, { fields: { title: 'titleValue4' } }] },
    ]

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array.map((x)=>{
     const filedsArray = [...x.obj]
      x.obj = []
      filedsArray.forEach((y)=>{
         x.obj.push({title:y.fields.title})                
      })
     return x
 })

console.log(map1);
```